# How to index Tomboy notes with Recoll?

Tags: search, tomboy, indexing, recoll

I would like to index the notes from Tomboy using the recoll desktop search engine.

The notes are in [XML](https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/Tomboy/NoteXmlFormat), stored in .local/share/tomboy.

How to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Tomboy and Gnote files are directly supported by the newer Recoll 1.19 release which you can get for Ubuntu from the Recoll PPA.

If you want to stay with the default Ubuntu package, it's easy to retrofit support:

Edit ~/.recoll/mimemap, add the following line:

```
.note = application/x-gnote
```

Edit ~/.recoll/mimeconf, add the following lines:

```
[index]
application/x-gnote = exec rclxml
```

Edit ~/.recoll/mimeview, add the following lines:

```
[view]
application/x-gnote = tomboy %f
```

Then retrieve the rclxml filter from: http://www.lesbonscomptes.com/recoll/filters/rclxml

Copy it to /usr/share/recoll/filters and  make it executable (chmod +x rclxml). It will need xsltproc, but this is probably already on your system (else get it with the package manager).

The easiest way to make sure the files are indexed may be to just run a full indexing pass (recollindex -z). There are other ways, but this answer is already long enough :)